# Unable to login to Microsoft Teams (Windows)

Tags: windows, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to log into Microsoft Teams but getting this error everytime:

[image]:

I've tried to delete the `Teams` folder under `%APPDATA%` however it did not solved the problem.
The username/password pair is confirmed correct since I a Teams App on a different PC which works fine.

I've checked the logs and here's the last output:

```
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- event -- errorCode: FailedOrchestration, errorStep: app_state_service, errorState: oops, errorUrl: undefined, scenarioMarkers: start;m_bootstrap;ds_start;ds_stop;cp_start;cp_stop;as_init;asi_end;as_ready;asc_main;cp_start;cp_stop;mw_start;asr_end;dlw_shown;uw_start;uw_stop;mw_end;da_start;sw_shown;sw_closed;da_stop;lw_app;p_start;p_stop;dlw_closed;wae_redirect;failure;, status: failure, scenario: UUID2, scenarioName: desktop_app_launch, name: desktop_app_launch, step: stop, sequence: 31, delta: 132823, scenarioDelta: 132823, elapsed: 132823, stepDelta: 0, vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 2, Scenario.Name: desktop_app_launch, Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status: failure,  
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- event -- errorCode: FailedOrchestration, errorStep: app_state_service, errorState: oops, errorUrl: undefined, status: success, scenario: UUID, scenarioName: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, name: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, step: start, sequence: 0, delta: 0, scenarioDelta: 0, elapsed: 154004, stepDelta: 0, vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, Scenario.Step: start, Scenario.Status: success,  
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- event -- errorCode: FailedOrchestration, errorStep: app_state_service, errorState: oops, errorUrl: undefined, status: success, scenario: UUID, scenarioName: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, name: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, step: stop, sequence: 1, delta: 1, scenarioDelta: 1, elapsed: 154005, stepDelta: 1, vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 3, Scenario.Name: desktop_web_app_error_redirect, Scenario.Step: stop, Scenario.Status: success,  
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- App oops page, disabling close to minimize. 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Main Window Show: app oops 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- event -- name: desktop_loading_window_timer_not_set, vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 2,  
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Clearing taskbar overlay icon 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- emit status indicator state change from Unknown to GeneralError 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Setting the taskbar overlay icon - We ran into an issue 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:20 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Added GeneralError (current state: Unknown -> GeneralError) 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:28 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Blur main window 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:28 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- info -- Is foreground set to false 
Fri Mar 13 2020 16:53:28 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time) <16980> -- event -- duration: 45.617000102996826, name: desktop_foreground_duration, vdiMode: 0, eventpdclevel: 2,
```

What could be the solution to be able to login?

**UPDATE:** I tried to copy the Teams folder from the working Teams app on the other PC and run Teams again: (Still did not worked)

[image]

Comment: You could try to uninstall Teams, scrub the disk and the registry and then reinstall.

Comment: @harrymc which registry to remove?

Comment: Search for an identifying string on disk and registry. I don't use Teams so cannot tell which one. For fast searching the registry use [regscanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html).

Comment: You will need to contact your System Administrator to resolve this particular problem with Teams.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22, this works for me, delete these files: '**settings**.json' and '**storage**.json':

```
rm -rf /home/YourUser/.config/Microsoft/'Microsoft Teams'/settings.json
rm -rf /home/YourUser/.config/Microsoft/'Microsoft Teams'/storage.json
```

There are other 2 MS teams folders on /.config

Answer (score 0):

I solved by opening the folder:

```
%appdata%\Microsoft\teams
```

and deleting the files "storage.json" and "settings.json". Restart Teams, and the login problem is gone.

This has been successfully tested after error 80270301.

Comment: Having tested this myself, this does not resolve the problem,

Comment: A deeper clean could help: https://www.onmsft.com/how-to/how-to-clear-your-microsoft-teams-cache-on-windows-10